# How to read MS Access db(.mdb file) in Spring batch and load into mysql db

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to read *.mdb file in Spring Batch and load into MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for MS Access database format by default in Spring Batch. The first step is to see how to read data from a MS Access database using Java, then you can create an `ItemReader` and use it in a Spring Batch job.

Now in order to connect to a MS Access db from Java, you can see the following questions/answers:

- [Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc/21955257#21955257)
- [How to connect java to Ms access Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45300178/how-to-connect-java-to-ms-access-database)

If you manage to create a jdbc `DataSource` pointing to a MS Access database, you can use the `JdbcCursorItemReader` (or `JdbcPagingItemReader`) and configure it with that `DataSource` (In this case there is no need to create a new reader).

Hope this helps.